# Vomit etching on stone floor

Tags: floor, marble, stain-removal

My daughter was sick on the stone (I assume it's marble - that's what it looks like) floor. It was cleaned up right away, but now there is a visible (from the right angle) dull spot on the floor exactly where it splashed. I believe this is etching from the acid. I don't believe it to be an actual stain.

What would be the best steps to take to remove this? Some kind of polish?

Comment: You could try something like this https://www.amazon.com/Akemi-Polishing-Fluid-10-2012/dp/B0041NYTMM Test it in a non-conspicuous area first though.

Comment: After you get it repolished, be sure to apply a sealer